# Css: Div positioning (2 multiple div's column (left - right) + center div)

Tags: css, html, positioning

Im trying to position the website like that:

```
-------------------
{   }{       }{   }
{   }{       }{   }
-----{       }-----
{   }{       }{   }
{   }{       }{   }
-------------------
```

Any ideas? tried float left and right but respective columns keep wrapping to the center making me unable to put the center div there.

Left and right columns are have leftcolumn and rightcolumn class

My code:
left column:

```
div.aside.gauche div.section.colonne.categories {
    height:460px;
    width:210px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-top:16px;
    border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    float:left;
}

 div.aside.gauche div.section.colonne.commentaires {
    height:85px;
    width:210px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-top:6px;
    border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    float:left;
}

div.aside.gauche div.section.colonne.magasins {
    height:321px;
    width:210px;
    border-style:solid;
    margin-top:6px;
    border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    float:left;
}
```

right column:

```
div.aside.droite div.section.colonne.recherche {
    height:460px;
    width:170px;
    border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    float:right;
}

div.aside.droite div.section.colonne.suivez {
    height:460px;
    width:170px;
    border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    float:right;
}

div.aside.droite div.section.colonne.partenaires {
    height:460px;
    width:170px;
    border: 1px solid black; -moz-border-radius: 0.3em 0.3em 0.3em;
    float:right;
}
```

center piece

```
div.milieu {
    float:left;
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: post your code, or make a jsfiddle

Comment: show us your CSS. Yet, searching the web about [three column layout](http://matthewjamestaylor.com/blog/perfect-3-column.htm) will help you

Answer (score 1):

Make sure all the column divs are using:

```
display:inline-block;
```

Comment: oh that could be useful, but ive found an alternative sorta say:

div.left.column {
 float:left;
 width:170px;
 height:1000px;
}

div.right.column {
 float:right;
 width:170px;
 height:1000px;
}

seems to work, would they be any problem with that?

Comment: @DAniel: That's a workabel solution, but not the best one. If you could post the code you have tried so far, then we can find the best solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution to your question:

http://jsfiddle.net/uZx4L/3/

Answer (score 0):

If all your divs will have specific heights and widths, you can use position:absolute for all your divs and specify where they go exactly.

```
 <div id='left_top'>
   ...
 </div>
 <div id='left_middle'>
   ...
 </div>
 <div id='left_bottom'>
   ...
 </div>
 <div id='center'>
   ...
 </div>
 <div id='right_top'>
   ...
 </div>
 <div id='right_middle'>
   ...
 </div>
 <div id='right_bottom'>
   ...
 </div>
```

Then with your css as such:

```
div#left_top {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:0px;
  width:210px;
  height:460px;
  background-color:red;
}

div#left_middle {
  position:absolute;
  top:460px;
  left:0px;
  width:210px;
  height:85px;
  background-color:yellow;
}

div#left_bottom {
  position:absolute;
  top:545px;
  left:0px;
  width:210px;
  height:321px;
  background-color:blue;
}

div#center {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  left:210px;
  right:170px;
  background-color:cyan;
}

div#right_top {
  position:absolute;
  top:0px;
  right:0px;
  width:170px;
  height:460px;
  background-color:magenta;
}

div#right_middle {
  position:absolute;
  top:460px;
  right:0px;
  width:170px;
  height:460px;
  background-color:green;
}

div#right_bottom {
  position:absolute;
  top:920px;
  right:0px;
  width:170px;
  height:460px;
  background-color:purple;
}
```

I specified background-color for each div so you can see where they are if you want to cut/paste it for a look see.  I used the sizes you specified.  But you could easily adapt this to have one or more of the divs grow so they're all equal sizes or change depending on the screen size.